# About the doer and knower

Tags: vipassana

During my meditation ,I experience automatically switch on  to breathe.what is this?Is it letting go of doer and knower?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

When the mind is quiet the breathing automatically becomes the object of meditation.

There is no need to try to watch the breathing. In fact, trying to watch the breathing is an obstacle to deep progress.

The Pali scriptures (SN 48.10; MN 118 at the emd) state the meditator makes 'letting go' the object of meditation.

Comment: Thank you for answer the question.could you be explain where I stand in meditation?

Comment: If the sense of 'doing' & the idea of 'knower' is naturally falling away and the mind is naturally uniting with the breath, this is how meditation should be. You should let this keep naturally happening. The purpose of meditation is to feel peace, contentment & for insight to develop. If the feeling of peace starts, this is the basis for determining where you stand. You will be satisfied with meditation. regards

Comment: I also experience the routine of the mind about thinking has  broken upto some extend and some about to be broken.mind does not disturb by loud noise as well.Are those things indicate improvement or still the same place?

Comment: For me, the only sign of progress is feeling a satisfying peace & contentment. Kind regards